# Wrap figure creating unwanted indents

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure

So I am wrapping a figure, but the figure is creating an unwanted paragraph with an indent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8.6in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}

\par Young’s experiment had wide-reaching effects in the wave vs particle debate and played a major role in reaching the current state of thought, but it also has practical uses outside of theoretical physics. An example is that of modern electrical wire production lines where you can find small boxes that encompass the wire as it exits the production line (Figure 2). 

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 0.25\textwidth]{Images/fig2.jpeg}
    \caption{Laser Wire Measure}
    \label{f2}    
\end{wrapfigure}

These boxes have small lasers within them that shine onto the wire and, using the same principles as Young’s experiment, ensure that the wires are of uniform diameter.
```

[image]

It creates a new paragraph at "These" for some reason, even though both of those "paragraphs" are in fact one.

Comment: The new paragraph is unrelated to `wrapfigure`. You explicitly specified a paragraph break with a blank line.  You also have a `\par` before the text but you never need `\par` in a document, use blank line, which is the same thing. Blank line or `\par` _ends_ a paragraph so used at the start it does nothing at all.

Comment: Where exactly do you want the figure to go?  The only thing weird is the line break after particle.

Comment: The paragraph at "These" is expected (remove the blank lines to avoid it). What is strange is the forced newline in the first line. Have you tried to remove `float`?